# Raphael JS Pie: Add ID to path slices

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael, pie-chart

I've seen this question asked over at the Raphael Google Groups, but after hours of searching there, and also on here, and Google, I cannot seem to find a solution.

I would simply like to be able to target my pie chart (svg path) slices using jQuery, but I cannot figure out how to add custom id's to the path tags - there is no ID attribute in there by default:

```
<path fill="#764c29" stroke="none" d="M350,350L350.6911881148345,94.00093308961084A256,256,0,0,1,561.8463375189659,206.2741175716762Z" style="stroke-width: 1; stroke-linejoin: round;" stroke-width="1" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
```

What would be ideal would be this:

```
<path **id="my_id"** fill="#764c29" stroke="none" d="M350,350L350.6911881148345,94.00093308961084A256,256,0,0,1,561.8463375189659,206.2741175716762Z" style="stroke-width: 1; stroke-linejoin: round;" stroke-width="1" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
```

Has anyone got an idea how this could be achieved?

This is the code I'm using to create the pie chart:

```
window.onload = function () {
var r = Raphael("holder");


var pie = r.g.piechart(350, 350, 256, [56, 104, 158, 23, 15, 6]);

pie.hover(function () {
    this.sector.stop();
    this.sector.animate({scale: [1.1, 1.1, this.cx, this.cy]}, 500, "bounce");

    }, function () {
        this.sector.animate({scale: [1, 1, this.cx, this.cy]}, 500, "bounce");
    });
```

};

Essentially, the reason I need to be able to do this, is so I can create some separate anchor triggers to perform the scale animations shown above.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the piechart object provides 3 ways to reach their sectors.

1) each function

```
pie.each(function(sector, cover, i) {
 sector.attr({/*...*/}); //raphael
 $(sector.node).foo(); //jquery
});
```

2) series object (for styling and transforming)

```
var i = 0; // 0 = 56, 1 = 104, 2 = 158 …

//raphael way to hide the first sector
pie.series.items[i].attr({ opacity : 0 });  

//jquery way to hide the first sector
$(pie.series.items[i].node).hide();
```

whereby i is the index of your data-array

demo: http://jsbin.com/eriqa5/2/edit

3) covers object (for mouse and touch events)

```
//raphael way to hover the first sector
pie.covers.items[0].hover(...);

//jquery way to hover the first sector
$(pie.covers.items[0].node).hover(...);
```

demo: http://jsbin.com/eriqa5/4/edit

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation. 

One thing I am still stuck on: using jQuery hover doesn't seem to work for the node:

`$(pie.series.items[0].node).hover(function () { 
    $('#test').hide();
 
}); `

Comment: Jamie, I updated my answer. you should use the covers-object for events. plz check the demo http://jsbin.com/eriqa5/4/edit

Comment: Genius, I was stuck on this for ages

Comment: One thing I did notice is that for some reason the item[i] index did not always represent the index of the passed in array. Instead I had to loop through and inspect each item[i].value.order to identifiy the correct one. Just in case anyone else has a problem with this. Possible new version maybe?