# Raphael JS PieChart selecting sections

Tags: javascript, html, css, raphael

I have used the JS library Raphael to create a pie chart.  I am wanting to assign each sector some text so that I can display the text in the middle of the circle when you hover over a specific section.  So first I need to select a specific section of the circle and assign it as a variable and add text to it.  Can anyone help me figure out how to select the first section in the circle??

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>g·Raphaël Dynamic Pie Chart</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="demo.css" media="screen">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="demo-print.css" media="print">
        <script src="raphael.js"></script>
        <script src="g.raphael.js"></script>
        <script src="g.pie.js"></script>

        <style type="text/css">

        body {
    background: #fff;
    font: 100.01% "Fontin Sans", Fontin-Sans, "Myriad Pro", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Lucida, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #000;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

#holder {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 640px;
    height: 480px;
}

p {
    text-align: left;
    margin: .5em 2em;
}

        </style>

        <script>
        //BUG FOUND if the user scrolls over where the original sector would be and keeps going in and out of the original region
        //the sector keeps getting bigger and bigger....it is tougher to do with a smaller animation time

            window.onload = function () {
                //creates raphael canvas located at the specified id
                var r = Raphael("holder"),
                    //creates piechart in raphael (x, y, radius) [  amounts which are distributed according to sum ]  ??legend?? ??href??
                    pie = r.piechart(320, 240, 100, [70,20,5,5], { legend: ["%%.%% - Enterprise Users", "IE Users"], legendpos: "southeast", href: ["http://raphaeljs.com", "http://g.raphaeljs.com"]});

                    //inner circle
                    innner = r.circle(320,240, 60).attr("fill", "red");
                    //invisible circle for text
                    innertext = r.circle(320,240,60).attr({"fill-opacity":"0"});

                //writes text at specified location
                r.text(320, 100, "Interactive Pie Chart").attr({ font: "20px sans-serif" });
                pie.hover(function () {
                    //if the user tries hovering over while the animation is finishing up in the specified time for the
                    //animation to last the user will not get the desired effect.  this says that the animation is over
                    //once the function is called again
                    this.sector.stop();
                    //describes how big the sector will be when hovered over
                    this.sector.scale(1.1, 1.1, this.cx, this.cy);

                    //does the same as above telling the legends to stop and what to do during animation
                    if (this.label) {
                        this.label[0].stop();
                        this.label[0].attr({ r: 7.5 });
                        this.label[1].attr({ "font-weight": 800 });
                    }
                }, function () {
                    //tells the selected sector to animate at the given speed and animation type
                    this.sector.animate({ transform: 's1 1 ' + this.cx + ' ' + this.cy }, 500, "bounce");

                    //creates the labesls in the legend and describes how they will be animated
                    if (this.label) {
                        this.label[0].animate({ r: 5 }, 500, "linear");
                        this.label[1].attr({ "font-weight": 400 });
                    }
                });
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body class="raphael" id="g.raphael.dmitry.baranovskiy.com">
        <div id="holder"></div>
        <p>
            Pie chart with legend, hyperlinks on two first sectors and hover effect.
        </p>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: As a side note, I would highly recommend switching to a real JS charting library like Highcharts, which actually has documentation.

Comment: Raphael is a REAL charting library!! Don't rip on it!!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I found the answer to what I was looking for in this post.....

[Raphael JS Pie: Add ID to path slices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789832/raphael-js-pie-add-id-to-path-slices)

This person is basically looking for the same thing.  Thanks to all of those who tried helping me.